# USB 3.0 ports not working (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, usb

I bought an Asus X550VX laptop a few weeks ago and installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 on it. For a week or so everything worked fine, until one of the USB 3.0 ports stopped working. Soon after that, the other port stopped working too. The one USB 2 port still works fine. When I connect my phone to a USB 3 port it charges, but Ubuntu doesn't recognize that a device is connected. My wireless mouse doesn't work either on those ports.

I've googled around but nothing seems to help. I've updated my bios and added a "pci=nomsi" line to grub file. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try unplugging everything and trying one device / cable at a time.

Comment: Tried that and nothing works. Not my phone, mouse or flash drive.

Answer (score 8):

This ought to do it:

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Find this line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`
3. Change it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"`
4. Save
5. Run `sudo update-grub`
6. Reboot

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Worked perfectly in Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: what does that do?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 and it's working. Idk for how long.
If it stop working again i'll update this comment :3

Comment: Better approach: `echo 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX iommu=soft"' > /etc/default/grub.d/fix-usb3-ports.cfg && update-grub`. You may want to remember the reason for making such a configuration change in the future.