# USB 3.1 mass storage not working in USB 3.1 port in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: grub2, usb, mount

I recently upgraded form 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Lenovo G50-45. I also have dual boot with windows 10.
3.1 flash drive mounts automatically to USB 2.0 port, but cannot be seen in 3.1 port.

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 28,9 GiB, 31004295168 bytes, 60555264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd74714c1

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 60555263 60553216 28,9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Other usb flash 2.0 can be read in both ports (2.0, 3.1). Maybe the problem is in permissions, but I cannot change them (I show only important line).

For usb 3.1 flash:

```
ls -all

drwxr-xr-x  10 honza honza 16384 led  1  1970 6B85-5FA8
```

Here is output of command:

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/4p, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 13, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/4p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 16, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
```

Is there any way how to mount, or any workaround?

I also found out, that other USB 3.1 device (Seagate Maxtor 2 TB disk) mounts to USB 2.0 port and does not to 3.1 port.

```
ls -all
drwxrwxrwx  1 honza honza 8192 lis 23 15:34 Maxtor
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lsusb -t` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that answer from [USB 3.0 ports not working (16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890585/usb-3-0-ports-not-working-16-0) works for my Lenovo G50-45, too.

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
Find this line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
Change it to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"
Save
Reboot
```

Now I can see USB disk like:

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
    **|__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M**
/:  Bus 05.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/4p, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-pci/4p, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
```

BUT (WARNING) I should not use "safely remove" it leads to complete STOP of Ubuntu, which needs hard restart. I can do only "eject" or "unmount device".
(Mounting to USB 2.0 port seems to work fine, as it did.)